# Identify a story in which Jumanji/Zathura type board game gave a player a hot mermaid wife

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember watching a telefilm or movie on TV in early 00s. I didn't know its name even that time (I missed the beginning and end). In it, there was a board game similar to Jumanji (movie version, not TV show version) and Zathura. The board game used to change the real world based on the messages displayed after each move (like meteor shower in Zathura). Here are more details I recalled:

- Something was at stake (I missed that part), so the players needed to finish the game to get back to normal life.
- A player rolled the dice and a message appeared saying he would get love of his life, but in water (not exact words). And, there appeared a hot mermaid in a pool nearby (the pool wasn't there before).
- I remember the features of that mermaid very clearly: She had a slim body. Her upper body was white and lower body (the fish part) was sparkling blue. She was blonde and she had blue eyes. She was naked. Although there was a sea shell on her breasts, her pink nipples were clearly visible. But, I am not 100% sure. It can be this shell:

[image: breast shell]

- When the player saw her, it was love at first sight. And, when he went near her, she pulled him inside the water. He started to drown, but then she kissed him. Next moment, he found himself breathing underwater (perhaps, he got a gill).
- When the player didn't return for several minutes, the other player started to get worried and jumped in the pool to save him. But, he couldn't find anything. That small looking pool was very deep. He got out. He thought the other player was dead.
- He got out of the house and returned there after years. He remembered something. When he removed spider webs and cleared the dust, he saw the board game and the pool was still there. He talked to himself that if pool was still there, could this be that the game would have kept the other player alive.
- He brought an oxygen cylinder and jumped into the water. After searching, he found the other player at last.
- Now, he had kids with that mermaid. None of the kids had legs (everyone had fish tails).
- The last thing I remember: They had arguments. One player said that they had to finish the game to return back to normal life. The other said that he was having perfect life and playing further would kick his family out of existence and he would protect his family at all cost.

Can you please identify this telefilm or movie?

Comment: It sounds like you watched Jumanji followed by anime porn.

Comment: Certainly an interesting concept...